# How to select by default current date with datepicker?

Tags: jquery

There is a datePicker in a js fiel :

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        defaultDate: +0,
        showOtherMonths:true,
        autoSize: true,
        appendText: '(dd-mm-yyyy)',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```

How to make current date selected by default when the datepicker is shown ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

call this

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("setDate", (new Date()));
$( ".datepicker" ).val('');
```

after

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        defaultDate: +0,
        showOtherMonths:true,
        autoSize: true,
        appendText: '(dd-mm-yyyy)',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zVPVJ/)

Comment: It works ; BUT input field has the current date as default value !

Comment: Current date is not selected when adding `$( ".datepicker" ).val('');` !

Comment: @pheromix i have added a demo you can check it there